# TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, typeerror

`epsData` is a two-dimensional array consisting of `Dates` and `StockID`.

I took out some of the code in order to make it simple.

The code calls the functions `Generate` and `neweps`, `epsData` is passed by the engine. I am not sure why it gives an error when I try to pass the array `epsss` to the `SUE()` function.

I tried to remove the extra bracket in array (if any) by using flatten function but that does not help.

`SUE()` is supposed to loop through the array and find the 4th last different value and then store these in an array.

I get this error:

```
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

with the three lines marked below:

```
def lastdifferentvalue(vals,datas,i):
  sizes=len(datas)
  j=sizes-1
  values=0
  while (i>0) and (j>=0):
    if logical_and((vals-datas[j]!=0),(datas[j]!=0),(datas[j-1]!=0)): # !! HERE !!
      i=i-1
      values=datas[j-1]
    j=j-1
  return j, values

def SUE(datas):
  sizes=len(datas)
  j=sizes-1
  values=0
  sues=zeros(8)
  eps1=datas[j]
  i=7
  while (j>0) and (i>=0) :
    counts, eps2=lastdifferentvalue(eps1,array(datas[0:j]),4)
    if eps2!=0:
      sues[i]=eps1-eps2
      i=i-1
      j,eps1=lastdifferentvalue(eps1,datas[0:j],1) # !! HERE !!

  stddev=std(SUE)
  sue7=SUE[7]
  return stddev,sue7          

def Generate(di,alpha):      

    #the code below loops through the data. neweps is a two dimensional array of floats [dates, stockid]                     
    for ii in range(0,len(alpha)):
      if (epss[2,ii]-epss[1,ii]!=0) and (epss[2,ii]!=0) and (epss[1,ii]!=0):
        predata=0
        epsss= neweps[di-delay-250:di-delay+1,ii]
        stddevs,suedata= SUE(array(epsss.flatten())) # !! HERE !!
```

Comment: the three lines where I can that error have "**" at the begining and end. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the _minimum_ program that demonstrates the problem, along with supporting input and desired output. The process of reducing the code to the smallest possible that still duplicates the problem often shows what the problem is.

Comment: Bolding doesn't work inside code blocks - I updated it to a comment so that the code could be run. Adjust if needed.

Comment: i have edited the code and tried to summarize it. some data is passed here from the engine. Please can you help me look into what the issue might be? thanks a lot

Comment: hi all can anyone please have a look at my question. thanks alot!

Comment: This code is borderline unreadable, you're just wading deeper and deeper. **Please consider using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org)**; it implements everything you need here, far more performant, code is shorter and more readable. If you give us a MRE including generating some random-seeded data, I will post the pandas code. It's probably only 5-10 lines in pandas.

Comment: About half your variables are either declared and never used or used when undefined. Unless you are able to ask a question that is able to be answered you can't expect to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're using [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html), in the form of

```
np.logical_and(a, b, c)
```

with the meaning that you'd like to take the logical and of the three. If you check the documentation, though, that's not what it does. It's interpreting `c` as the array where you intend to store the results.

You probably mean here something like

```
np.logical_and(a, np.logical_and(b, c))
```

or

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(np.logical_and, [a, b, c])
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
if logical_and((vals-datas[j]!=0),(datas[j]!=0),(datas[j-1]!=0))
```

has two errors:

1. Presumably you are wanting to perform a `logical_and` over `(vals-datas[j] != 0)` **and** `(datas[j] != 0)` **and** `(datas[j-1] != 0)`.  However `numpy.logical_and` only takes two *input* parameters, the third if passed is assumed to be an *output* array.  Thus if you are wishing to have `numpy.logical_and` operate over three arrays it should be expressed as:

   ```
   logical_and(logical_and((vals-datas[j] != 0), (datas[j] != 0)), (datas[j-1] != 0))
   ```
2. In any case, using a `logical_and` in an `if` statement makes no sense.  It returns an array and an array does not have a *truth value*.  That is, the result of a `logical_and` is an array of booleans, some of which are true and some false.  Are you wishing to check if they are *all* true?  Or if at least *some* are true?

   If the former, then you should test it as:

   ```
   if numpy.all(logical_and(...)):
      ...
   ```

   And if the latter then test it as:

   ```
   if numpy.any(logical_and(...)):
      ...
   ```